# my app was running fine but suddenly this error shown in debug console when i run flutter android app

Tags: android, flutter

this is the error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/home/anees/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1159
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command '/home/anees/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

i tried running flutter clean
i tried adding all dependencies again.
restarted visual studio code
but all in vain
it was just fine but now it is causing errors

Comment: And what do you receive when you run flutter with option --stacktrace or --debug?

Comment: same issue , you solved it ?